# Converting a Cordova/OnsenUI App to standard WebApp

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

This is a question that is a separate topic, but related to another question I have posted, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985323/using-onsenui-for-webapps-with-apache-web-servers

I have followed the guides to creating apps with Cordova and OnsenUI with node.js via npm, and my environment is working great (with limited fuss, brilliant!) and I have quickly developed my app in the environment and tested on various devices with the emulators.

What I would like to do, is convert this native iOS/Android app to a standard web app, is this possible? There is no functionality that couldn't be performed in a standard HTML5 webapp, but the use on OnsenUI has sped my UI Design phase up immensely so I'd like to keep that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I would like to do, is convert this native iOS/Android app to a standard web app, is this possible?

If you doesn't use native API like Camera, Media, Audio, It is easy. Just locate the files under the www directory into the your server's docroot.